# Rest Builder Client post request with header issue grails

Tags: rest, grails, restclientbuilder

I am trying post request with rest client builder.

We have following code

```
RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()
rest = rest.post("https://api..com/ff/one"){
    header 'x-pushbots-appid', '550de488b4569'
    header 'x-pushbots-secret', 'e6717aea77d'
    contentType "application/json"
    json {
        token ="APA91bG9rUbBPURYejC1uzDLbqUMaeHulCtBNIYUokqV5QUwelLygKi8c5c2kD2lq05DXiiKJEDgH8NGfM6DFGhCETgSuX5kOr"
        platform="1"
        msg ="sarath test from API call"
        sound ="ding"
        badge ="badge"
        payload ="JSON"
    }
}
```

Postman is giving correct result for this request , while  using rest client builder plugin, response is coming as null.
I checked in api doc and code looks fine.

Comment: Start with `json {` in one line instead of two lines as updated in the question. `json()` takes a closure.

Comment: On a second look, `rest = rest.post("https://api..com/ff/one"){` , the response is assigned back as `RestBuilder` which is incorrect. It should be  `RestResponse response = rest.post("https://api..com/ff/one"){ .. }` or just `def response`.

Comment: hey thanks..def response chnage i addded my mistake during paste code..is they is some way to debug code ..this little bit urgent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems i was wrong version of json builder.
Issue got fixed after using compile ":rest-client-builder:2.1.1"